# Best way to package Resources in the microservices

Tags: java, microservices

I want to know if there is a best practice around packaging the `Resource` classes of micro-services. By `Resource` classes I mean the contracts (like request, responses and error objects of the service)

- Package inside the micro-service
- Package as separate `jar` etc and version control it separately and include dependency in the actual micro-service.

Are there any best practices around this? I generally favour packaging them separately and keep it as lean as possible. Reason being the consumers of the service can use them and get get the marshalling/un-marshalling features without writing pojos of their own.

My main context of question is from java language.

Many thanks

Comment: I could come up with a handful of reasons to go or not to go down that way. It depends on too many things and none is technical since, technically, both are possible. The problem is the tradeoffs which I'm sure you already weight and contrasted with your SDLC needs.  Unless you can provide with more context and detail and edit the question in such a way we can say if it's adequate or convenient to your particular scenario, I'm afraid of the question to be either too broad or mainly opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

If the majority of micro-services use the same language, there is something to say for having separate packages for the DTOs that are communicated over each service's API.

It makes it a lot harder for different teams to interpret the written (or even oral) API specifications differently and it might also make it easier to facilitate compatibility between API versions.

If the micro-services use different languages to a large extent, then it is harder to share such code packages and you need to rely on unambiguous, written, API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Extraction of all POJO/DTOs into separate jar files might have some benefits, but it would make different issues for you. Everything is based on your application scope and design and all of the things that I'm going to mention might be tentatively applicable in your scenario, So you can consider them in your design and refining your architecture.
So, let's think together what are the benefits of this extraction and what are actions need to be taken for this:

**Pros of Moving DTOs/POJOs into external JAR**

- All of the projects can use the POJOs just by importing them.
- If we want to update a POJO, it needs to be modified in one place and the other projects need to only update the version ( by cleaning their project and updating the POM version, unless they are using the latest which might be dangerous )

**Cons of Moving DTOs/POJOs into external JAR**

- How you are going to extract JAR files, all of the DTOs for different Microservices into one JAR? Or each group of DTOs needs to be placed in different JARs? It somehow needs more effort for managing it properly.
- How you are going to manage the update of your microservices? for a simple modification in one of them which is irrelevant to others, you might need to re-deploy all of the Microservices again and test everything to make sure everything is working fine. On another hand, you could do some small changes in the traditional way by just only by thinking about how to make it backward compatible while it's not easy in this case.
- Version management of these JAR files is not easy.
- There are headaches for switching between different projects for developers, plus they need to maintain different Git repositories.
- You need to have some private Maven repositories for facilitating the management of these JAR packages and also consider this in your CI/CD processes.

**So, what we should do?**
Actually, As I told you in the first place. I think it completely depends on your story and there are different patterns regarding this subject and If I want to add more solutions for your case, I should say why you are not importing all of your projects into the same JAR file? I'm talking about MONORepo. you can find more information here ([Mono Repo in JAVA](https://dev.to/kgunnerud/our-experience-monorepo-with-java-maven-and-github-actions-2aho)).

Finally, Make your microservices scopes clear and then you can decide what is the best approach for you. completely think about Maintainability, Deployment, Version Management, Flexibility, Agility, How to test the project, and Cost of the development and operation.